# Finding Observer Latitude/Longitude - In Simple Terms

Tags: the-sun, positional-astronomy

I was wondering if someone could explain to me in simple terms how to determine the observer latitude/longitude at a given location. For instance, if an observer is positioned at Cleveland, Ohio, how can I find where the sun and moon is at a certain time of the day?

I am familiar with latitude and longitude but I always retrieve that from Google. Is this the same as those Geographic coordinates or are the observer values different?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You might be asking separate questions. Your latitude and longitude on Earth are not related to the position of the sun and moon.

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy SE, Sue! I've edited your question so other users may find it easier to read and understand.

Comment: I need to detect the local solar eclipse at a certain location for the solar eclipse we had back in August of 2017. The equation has the parameters of the geographic latitude of the observer (deg), geographic longitude of the observer (deg). The example I have is 60 for the latitude observer and 0 for the longitude observer.

Comment: The observer latitude and longitude is the latitude and longitude of the observer. It's the values you get from Google maps. For Cleveland OH, that is 41.5, -81.7

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was thinking it might be but I have never heard it referenced as the observer lat/long. Appreciate it.